# Using a Combobox to select and option button in excel userform

Tags: vba, excel, userform, radio-button

I am new to vba and am having some trouble with a userform.
I am trying have it so that when a selection in a combobox contains a certain letter, an option button is selected.

The code I have tried to use is:-

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
If ComboBox1.Value = "*C*" Then
    OptionButton3.Value = True
    End If
If ComboBox1.Value = "FR 850 C BLUE" Then
    TextBox2.Value = "BLUE"
    End If
If ComboBox1.Value = "FR 850 C WHITE" Then
    TextBox2.Value = "WHITE"
    End If
End Sub
```

However, `TextBox2` is only visible as follows:

```
Private Sub OptionButton3_Click()
TextBox2.Visible = True
With Me.TextBox2
    .Value = "Colour here"
    .SetFocus
    .SelStart = 0
    .SelLength = Len(.Text)
End With
End Sub
```

See [this printscreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qE5T8.png) (see below) of the userform when an option containing "C" is selected - `OptionButton3` remains unselected.

[image: printscreen]

Also I have tried to code so that when "FR 850 C BLUE" is selected, `TextBox2` will show "BLUE".  I suspect once I find a fix to the first part this will work better, but, as [this printscreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dn0c3.png) (see below) shows, if you select `OptionButton3` after "FR 850 C BLUE" in `Combobox1`, `TextBox2` doesn't show "BLUE", as I would wish it.

[image: printscreen]

Can anyone help? I suspect I've missed something out somewhere...

Any/all comments welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are stating:

```
If ComboBox1.Value = "*C*" Then
```

This means, if `ComboBox1.Value` equals `"*C*"` do something.
To check if a Value partially matches you use `Like`:

```
If ComboBox1.Value Like "*C*" Then
```

Comment: Thanks very much, that sorted it! :)